# How to show that $v,v^1, \cdots, v^n$ are linearly independent?

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

How do I make sure that $v, v^1, \cdots, v^n$ are linearly independent in order to be a basis for $W\ $?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $n$ minimal such that $v^{n+1}$ is linearly dependent on the previous vectors $v^0,\ldots,v^n$, which value exists because of finite dimensionality. Note that $W$ is by definition the smallest $\rho(x)$-stable subspace containing$~v$, and for $n$ as determined above the subspace spanned by $v^0,\ldots,v^n$ is such a subspace. Note that $n=\dim(W)-1$, it would have been easier if a name had been given to $n+1$.

Comment: Can an eigenvector of $x$ be chosen in such a way that it is contained in $W$?

Comment: Since $W$ is $\rho(x)$-stable we can restrict $\rho(x)$ to $W$, and the restriction has eigenvectors (like any endomorphism of a finite nonzero dimensional $\Bbb C$-vector space) and these are eigenvectors of $\rho(x)$ that lie in $W$.